# Problem in import statement of databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-databinding

I cannot import databinding to my project. I enabled databinding and imported the databinding class in my kotlin code but I get unresolved error.

I verified my build.gradle (:app) file and there is no issue there and I had put the correct statements that enable databinding and the build is successful. I still got the error. I cleaned and re
built the project but still the error persists. I also invalidated the cache and restarted the project but still the error persists.

Comment: please add your gradle codes and also your usage of it

Comment: hi pls use this link for gradle code and main activity code: https://pastebin.com/exteAQPn